# Vitali Covering Theorem: Filling open sets with closed ball

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have a question concerning the Proof of the Vitali Covering Theorem in Evans (Thm. 1.26, p. 35). So the Theorem states that we can cover any open, bounded set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ by countable many closed, disjoint balls with radii smaller than any constant $\delta > 0$ up to a Lebesgue nullset.

In the proof, it is stated that given some $\theta \in (1- \frac{1}{5^n}, 1)$, we find some countable family $\tilde{G}$ such that
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}^n(\Omega\setminus\cup_{B \in \tilde{G}} B) \leq (1- \frac{1}{5^n}) \mathcal{L}^n(\Omega).
\end{equation}
This, I do understand. But then it says that we can find a finite subfamily $G \subset \tilde{G}$ such that
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}^n(\Omega \setminus \cup_{B \in G} B) \leq  \theta \mathcal{L}^n(\Omega).
\end{equation}

Why does this hold? I had the feeling it has something to  do with the inner regularity of the Lebesgue measure, but don't see how it works out.

Comment: You should edit your question. The closed balls are required to be disjoint. If you drop this requirement, then $\Omega$ can trivially be covered by countably many closed ball with small radii.

Comment: @PaulFrost: Why do the covering balls have to be closed?

Comment: @Hans This is what the Vitali covering theorem wants to have.

Comment: @PaulFrost: I am asking which part of the proof would fail had the balls been not closed.

Comment: @Hans I do not know, I was just commenting on the question which deals with closed balls.

Answer (score 0):

The key of the question is Borel sets are Lebesgue-measurable.

$$\mathcal{L}^n(\Omega \backslash \cup_{B\in \tilde{G}} B)\leq (1-\frac{1}{5^n})\mathcal{L}^n(\Omega) < \theta \mathcal{L}^n(\Omega)$$

Note closed balls in $B$ are countable(Vitali’s Covering Theorem), so we have:
$$\Omega \backslash \cup_{B\in \tilde{G}} B = \Omega - \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} B_k=lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}(\Omega - \cup_{k=1}^{m} B_k)$$

Notice $(\Omega - \cup_{k=1}^{m} B_k)$ is decreasing by m, $\Omega$ and $\{B_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ are all Lebesgue-measurable(closed sets and open sets are Borel sets), wolg we assume $\mathcal{L}^n(\Omega) < \infty$, we have:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}^n(\Omega \backslash \cup_{B\in \tilde{G}} B) & = lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} \mathcal{L}^n(\Omega - \cup_{k=1}^m B_k)\\\\
& < \theta \mathcal{L}^n(\Omega)
\end{align}$$

And by definition of limit, $\exists m_0\in N_{+}$ s.t. $$\mathcal{L}^n(\Omega - \cup_{k=1}^{m_0}B_k)\leq \theta \mathcal{L}^n(\Omega)$$

If $\mathcal{L}^n(\Omega) = \infty$, we apply the above to  $\Omega_m=\{x\in \Omega | m<|x|< m+1\}$